# $f-1$, $f$, $f+1$ cannot be all square

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, induction

I'm having trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field with characteristic $\neq 2$, and let $f \in k[X]$. Show that $f-1$, $f$ and $f+1$ are all square only if $f \in k$.

Here's what I have so far: suppose $f = g^2$ for some $g \in k[X] \setminus k$. Then $f - 1 = g^2 - 1 = (g+1)(g-1)$. Since $k$ is a field of characteristic other than 2, $(g+1)$ and $(g-1)$ have completely disjoint sets of zeroes. This means that, if $f-1$ is square, then so are $g-1$ and $g+1$.

I think proving by induction on the polynomial's degree would be the best bet here, and it seems I somehow have to connect $f+1$ being square with $g$ also being a square (so I can apply the induction hypothesis). What am I missing?

Comment: Try starting with $f+1$ instead of $f$. You'll end up with $g^2 - 2$, which is decomposable into $(g + \sqrt{2})(g - \sqrt{2})$, and those roots are guaranteed to exist because $k$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: $g-1=u^2,\ g+1=v^2\implies v^2-u^2=2\implies(v-u)(v+u)=2$, so $\deg(v-u)=\deg(v+u)=0\implies\deg u=\deg v=0\implies\deg g=0\implies\deg f=0$.

Comment: @user26857 Simpler than I thought! ....and no need for induction.